# Using streaming to convert one multidimensional array to another

Tags: system-verilog

I have an array of bytes and a BFM that needs to stream that data into an AXI-S interface. My BFM has it's own memory that is N bits wide, depending on the parameterization of the bus.

I'm trying to copy my byte array into the BFMs memory using a streaming operator. The problem is that if the BFM memory is larger, due to it having a different width, the copy doesn't shift the byte array all the way to the LSByte of the BFM.

Example:

```
logic [7:0]  byte_array[59:0];   // 60 bytes of data
logic [31:0] bfm_memory[1:0];    // 64 bytes of data
```

The bfm_memory holds more bytes due to the bus width. If I stream the byte_array into the bfm_memory:

```
bfm_memory = {<<8{byte_array}};
```

It only streams in 60 bytes of data. The end result is that byte 0 of my byte array is not in byte 0 of the bfm_memory. It's 4 bytes short. How do I get the streaming operator to push the data all the way to the LSByte of the larger memory? Can I stream byte_array from its MSByte into the bfm_memory LSByte? Do I need to flip the endianess of the memories and stream from the other direction? (I'm thinking of the streaming like a shift register. Maybe I'm not understanding that correctly?)

Here's a more detailed example of the data. The byte array is the maximum size of a packet of data so it may be larger than the amount of data to transfer. In the case below only non-zero values are valid data. Due to the bus width bfm_memory is 12 bytes (not 10).

```
byte_array[9] = 00
byte_array[8] = 00
byte_array[7] = 88
byte_array[6] = 77
byte_array[5] = 66
byte_array[4] = 55
byte_array[3] = 44
byte_array[2] = 33
byte_array[1] = 22
byte_array[0] = 11

bfm_memory[2] = 32'h00008877
bfm_memory[1] = 32'h66554433
bfm_memory[0] = 32'h22110000
```

The desired result:

```
bfm_memory[2] = 32'h00000000
bfm_memory[1] = 32'h88776655
bfm_memory[0] = 32'h44332211
```

Comment: Your edits have change the requirements of the original question. "only non-zero values are valid data".  Please show the actual declarations of the data_array and bmf_memory. Are they dynamically sized? Will one always be larger than the other?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pad the smaller data size to the larger data size.

```
module top; 
  logic [7:0]  byte_array[59:0];    // 60 bytes of data
  logic [31:0] bfm_memory[15:0];    // 64 bytes of data
  initial begin
    byte_array = '{default:0, 9:9,8:8,7:7,6:6,5:5,4:4,3:3,2:2,1:1,0:0};
    bfm_memory = {>>{32'b0,byte_array}};
    $displayh("%p",bfm_memory);
  end
endmodule
```